# Solr 3.2 edismax

Tags: solr, edismax

I am trying to use the edismax defType and am running into the following error.

**HTTP ERROR : 400**
Unknown query type 'edismax'

The request handler in the solrconfig.xml file looks as follows

```
<requestHandler name="foobar" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="qf">block</str>
      <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

My goal is to do wildcard searches with this search handler.

We recently upgraded to use Solr 3.2 from 1.4. Is there a setting or a config that has to be change to allow edismax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*HTTP ERROR : 400 Unknown query type 'edismax'*
Its indicating an invalid query type parameter which is qt and not defType.

Are you trying to use `qt=edismax`, if so, this might result into this error as the request handler is named `foobar`.
You can rename `foobar` to `edismax` or use `qt=foobar`